# My title disappears when I use \pdfpages

Tags: pdf, titles, pdfpages

I have a IEEEtran template. I have a title and text. When I include a pdf file the title and text of the paper disappears and I can only see the included pdf. I want the pdf to be at the end of the paper (after the paper's text finishes). Can anyone help me fix this issue?

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}
\title{Title Here}

\author[1]{Author1}
\author[2]{Author2}
\affil[1]{Org1 \authorcr {\tt x@y.co}}
\affil[2]{Org2 \authorcr {\tt x@x.co}}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}


\section{Intro}
Section1


\appendix
\subsection{Appendix A}
\includepdf[pages=-]{/home/e/Documents/saudi_parents/survey/kau/survey_english}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put a `\clearpage` before `\includepdf`. But this a really interesting question. With `article` everything is fine, so it's related to the class.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem lies with `authblk`, a very old package to deal with blocks of names and affiliations

IEEE as his special ways (no brainer) to deal with authors and affiliations, defining the  blocks `\IEEEauthorblockN`  and `\IEEEauthorblockA` for that purpose.

This code compiles OK.

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
%\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}
\title{Title Here}
    
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{School of Electrical and\\
        Computer Engineering\\
        Georgia Institute of Technology\\
        Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\
        Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
    \and \\
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Homer Simpson}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
        Springfield, USA\\
        Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
    \and \\
    \IEEEauthorblockN{James Kirk\\  and Montgomery Scott}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\
        San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
        Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\
        Fax: (888) 555--1212}}  

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
2. \kant[2]
\end{abstract}

\section{Intro}
3. \kant[3-10]
\appendix

\subsection{Appendix A}
1. \kant[1]
\includepdf[pages=-]{IEEEtran_HOWTO}

\end{document}
```

[image: out114]

[image: outb]